# Telerik asp.net MVC Fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik asp.net MVC 3 file control in my Razor view  (`Catalog`/`Product` View) like this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Upload()
    .Name("orderImageAtachment")
    .Async(async => async.Save("Save", "Catalog").AutoUpload(true))
    .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnSuccess("ItemImageOnSuccess")
        .OnError("ItemImageOnError")
    )
)
```

I have created an `ActionResult` like this:

```
 public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> orderImageAtachment, string CompID)
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "attachments" 
            foreach (var file in orderImageAtachment)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path. This needs to be stripped.
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Docs"), fileName);

                // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
            }
            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }
```

and client side functions like this:

```
  function onSuccess(e) {
        // Array with information about the uploaded files
        var files = e.files;

        if (e.operation == "upload") {
            alert("Successfully uploaded " + files.length + " files");
        }
    }


    function onError(e) {

        alert('Error in file upload');
        // Array with information about the uploaded files
        var files = e.files;

        if (e.operation == "upload") {
            alert("Failed to uploaded " + files.length + " files");
        }

        // Suppress the default error message
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

I get select button which opens browse window. But clicking it does nothing.... I am not sure whats wrong. Do I need to add something in web.config? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused at which point its not working, but I'm assuming its not hitting the action in your controller. I'd make sure you are trying a fairly small file, the default limit is 4mb.

Also it looks like the signature of your `Save` Action does not match the route you are giving it in the upload's `async.Save(...)`. I'm not sure it will matter since its a string, but you might try removing the Save actions's `CompID` parameter (doesn't look like its used in the snippet at least).

I'd try using fiddler or the developer tools in whichever browser you are using to see if u are getting a 404 error by chance.